# Using apply function to obtain only those rows that passes threshold in R

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to apply a filter on my data (which is in the form of matrix) with say 10 columns, 200 rows.

I want to retain only those rows that where the coefficient of variance is greater than a threshold. But with the code I have, it seems its printing the coefficient of variance for the rows passing threshold. I want it to just test if it passes threshold, but print the original data point in the matrix.

```
covar <- function(x) ( sd(x)/mean(x) )
evar <- apply(myMatrix,1,covar)
myMatrix_filt_var <-myMatrix[evar>2,]
```

Here threshold I set is 2.

What am I doing wrong ? Sorry just learning R.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong in what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` is your matrix, then,

```
m[apply(m, 1, function(x) sd(x)/mean(x) > 2), ]
```

should give you the filtered matrix. The idea is to obtain the coefficient of variation for every row *and check if it is > 2 inside*. This will return a logical vector from which by directly accessing it like `m[logical_vector, ]`, we can get those rows where the condition is TRUE.

You can use `na.rm = TRUE` if you want to remove NA values while calculating `sd` and `mean`.

Comment: But I don't think what you're doing is wrong. I've no idea why your code isn't working. It gives me the same result with your code.

Comment: maybe you're getting just 1 element which meets the threshold. Try with `myMatrix[eval > 2, , drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: Actually I figured what I was doing wrong. Instead of printing the original matrix back, I was printing the coefficient of variance.